# Why do I only get one daily quest?

Tags: hearthstone

I started playing Hearthstone and finished the tutorial and my first daily quests yesterday. As far as I understand I should get three new daily quests each day.

I only got one daily quest this morning. Did I misunderstand this and do I only get one daily quest? Or do I have to do something specific to get the other ones?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You gain only one daily quest, but you can have up to 3 quests at the same time ([source](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest)). Note that you can abandon up to 1 quest a day and receive immediately another random one in its place.

Comment: Just for reference - the ability to abandon quests has been currently disabled due to bugs.

Comment: Abandoning quests was reenabled today.

Answer (score 5):

You only get one daily quest per day, but I think you can have up to 3 quests (accumulated over a number of days) total.

Happy questing! ;)